# Identifying Japanese language from UTF-8 base64 encoding

Tags: java, perl, utf-8, smtp

I have a SMTP email which is in Japanese and some part is in english.
The Subject of the email is encoded in UTF-8, base64.

Subject: =?UTF-8?B?5Y2K5bCO5L2T6KO96YCg6KOF572u44OX44Os44OT44Ol44O844OO44O8?=
 =?UTF-8?B?44OIIDog5b6M5bel56iL44Oh44O844Kr44O844GM5by344GE?=

How do I detect if this in Japanese/Chinese and decode it to Japanese/Chinese.

Can I acheive this in Perl/Java/Python?

Answer (score 5):

You have two steps here. First decode the header:

If you have an email, use a high-level email parser such as [Courriel](http://p3rl.org/Courriel). The [`subject` accessor](http://p3rl.org/Courriel#email-subject) will return the decoded subject.

If you just have the string, use [Encode::MIME::Header](http://p3rl.org/Encode%3a%3aMIME%3a%3aHeader):

```
use Encode qw(decode);
decode 'MIME-Header', 'Subject: =?UTF-8?B?5Y2K5bCO5L2T6KO96YCg6KOF572u44OX44Os44OT44Ol44O844OO44O8?= =?UTF-8?B?44OIIDog5b6M5bel56iL44Oh44O844Kr44O844GM5by344GE?='
__END__
Subject: 半導体製造装置プレビューノート : 後工程メーカーが強い
```

The second step is to find out the language. As a human, I can already tell that this is Japanese. The [kana](http://enwp.org/Kana) characters are the clue, they only occur in Japanese writing. If that's all you need, then if the string matches [`\p{Kana}`](http://p3rl.org/recharclass#Unicode-Properties), it's likely Japanese.

For a more general solution, you use a language detection library such as [Lingua::Identify](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aIdentify)**[::CLD](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aIdentify%3a%3aCLD)**, [Lingua::Ident](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aIdent), [Lingua::Lid](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aLid), [Lingua::YALI](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aYALI), [WebService::Google::Language](http://p3rl.org/WebService%3a%3aGoogle%3a%3aLanguage).

Comment: For anyone landing here, there is a very decent perl module [Lingua::Guess](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::Guess), which you could use in command line, like: `echo "このモジュールを上手く使えるかな。" | perl -MLingua::Guess -MEncode=decode_utf8 -nlE 'say "Language is ", Lingua::Guess->new->guess( decode_utf8($_) )->[0]->{name}'` which would produce `Language is japanese`

Answer (score 1):

You may have to check these

[chardet](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/intl/chardet/) character set detection developed by Mozilla used in FireFox. Source code

[jchardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/) is a java port of the source from mozilla's automatic charset detection algorithm.

Comment: +1 The only answer that actually answer the question.

Comment: The Perl ports of that library are mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970660/how-can-i-guess-the-encoding-of-a-string-in-perl

Comment: -1, but it's the wrong tool, the question asked for language detection, not encoding detection.

Answer (score -1):

With Java, you need a library to decode your Base 64 string to binary, for example [apache codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

Then it's straigthforward:

```
  byte[] b = Base64.decodeBase64("5Y2K5bCO5L2T6KO96YCg6KOF572u44OX44Os44OT44Ol44O844OO44O8");
  String s = new String(b, "UTF-8");
  System.out.println(s);
```

It prints: `半導体製造装置プレビューノー` (I don't know what it means, but it sure looks like japanese).

Comment: How can I identify  which language it is in the code from the output text?

Comment: If you want to recognize if the text is Japanese or English, I suggest to look at https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/.

Comment: This code actually prints out ??????????????. Should I change the language settings for it to print japanese in eclipse?

Comment: I don't see how it can print ?????????. Be sure to parse only the part of the String between =?UTF-8?B? and ?= (there are two parts in the subject).

Comment: I changed the text file encoding to UTF-8 in the project Properties of eclipse and it worked.