# Autodetect the character encoding when reading a file

Tags: perl, io, character-encoding

I sometimes have to read text files from external sources, which can use various character encodings; usually UTF-8, Latin-1 or Windows CP-1252.

Is there a way to conveniently read these files, autodetecting the encoding like editors such as Vim do?

I'm hoping for something as simple as:

```
open(my $f, '<:encoding(autodetect)', 'foo.txt') or die 'Oops: $!';
```

Note that [Encode::Guess](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Guess) does not do the trick: it only works if an encoding can be unambiguously detected, otherwise it croaks.  Most UTF-8 data is nominally valid latin-1 data, so it fails on UTF-8 files.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.020;
use warnings;

use Encode;
use Encode::Guess qw(utf-8 cp1252);

binmode STDOUT => 'utf8';

my $utf8 = "H\x{C3}\x{A9}llo, W\x{C3}\x{B8}rld!"; # "Héllo, Wørld!" in UTF-8
my $latin = "H\x{E9}llo, W\x{F8}rld!";            # "Héllo, Wørld!" in CP-1252

# Version 1
my $enc1 = Encode::Guess->guess($latin);
if (ref($enc1)) {
    say $enc1->name, ': ', $enc1->decode($latin);
}
else {
    say "Oops: $enc1";
}
my $enc2 = Encode::Guess->guess($utf8);
if (ref($enc2)) {
    say $enc2->name, ': ', $enc2->decode($utf8);
}
else {
    say "Oops: $enc2";
}

# Version 2
say decode("Guess", $latin);
say decode("Guess", $utf8);
```

Output:

```
cp1252: Héllo, Wørld!
Oops: utf-8-strict or utf8 or cp1252
Héllo, Wørld!
cp1252 or utf-8-strict or utf8 at ./guesstest line 32.
```

The version under "Update" in Borodin's answer works only on UTF-8 data, but croaks on Latin-1 data.
`Encode::Guess` can simply not be used if you need to handle both UTF-8 and Latin-1 files.

This isn't intended to be the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970660/how-can-i-guess-the-encoding-of-a-string-in-perl): I'm looking for a way to autodetect when *opening* a file.

Comment: There is no way to reliably detect the character set for plain text.

Comment: Not 100% reliably, no.  But it should certainly be possible to do a “good enough” detection of the major charsets.  Even with a 1% failure rate it's still better than just assuming UTF-8 or Latin-1 and falling over or showing weird characters all the time.  (And vim, for instance, does a great job: I can't remember if ever misdetecting a file.)

Comment: Note that Windows 1252 (CP-1252) is ***not*** the same as ISO-8859-1. The former has printable characters in the first sixteen characters of the upper register `"\x80"` to `"\9F"` where the latter has the same range unassigned to leave space for the C1 control character set.

Comment: Windows-1252 (cp1252) is a superset of iso-8859-1, though.  (HTML5, for instance, uses windows-1252 as a default to deal with incorrectly specified Windows content.)

Comment: @mscha: I commented only because you wrote `latin-1/windows-1252` in your original post. Latin-1 and ISO-8859-1 are two names for the same encoding, but CP-1252 is different. When guessing an encoding it is best to assume that, if the sample data uses character codes `"\x80"` to `"\9F"` then it is using CP-1252 where the characters are printable. In Latin-1, the *Latin-1 Supplement* assigns control characters to this range, but I have never seen them used, and I would have thought the existing 32 ASCII control characters were sufficient for any purpose.

Comment: @TomB: Okay, I over-reached with my claim for ASCII. But UTF-7 is rare and even Microsoft are dropping UTF-16, even so `Encode::Guess` still identifies them both.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my current workaround.  Does the trick, at least for UTF-8 and Latin-1 (or Windows-1252) files.

```
use 5.024;
use experimental 'signatures';
use Encode qw(decode);

sub slurp($file)
{
    # Read the raw bytes
    local $/;
    open (my $fh, '<:raw', $file) or return undef();
    my $raw = <$fh>;
    close($fh);

    my $content;

    # Try to interpret the content as UTF-8
    eval { my $text = decode('utf-8', $raw, Encode::FB_CROAK); $content = $text };

    # If this failed, interpret as windows-1252 (a superset of iso-8859-1 and ascii)
    if (!$content) {
        eval { my $text = decode('windows-1252', $raw, Encode::FB_CROAK); $content = $text };
    }

    # If this failed, give up and use the raw bytes
    if (!$content) {
        $content = $raw;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps some words about how this works?

Comment: Added some comments to the code.

Comment: Comments only obfuscate code. A description in a parallel text document is far more useful.

Comment: It works for me. Like, it reads the file in bytes (raw) and convert it to given character set.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what possible encodings you may be dealing with.
Take a look at the
[`Encode::Guess`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Guess)
module

In general, it's very easy to tell whether you ***don't*** have an ASCII file as the code points are seven bits, so anything over 127 means it's not ASCII. It's also possible to tell reliably whether your file ***isn't*** UTF-8 as multi-byte characters have a specific sequence for their most-significant bits. Anything else is less reliable, but possible

I don't know what encodings you might be using, but this is the general idea. `Encode::Guess` is part of the core `Encode` module, and so shouldn't need installing

```
use Encode::Guess;

my $enc = guess_encoding($data, qw/ ascii cp1252 iso-8859-1 utf-8 /);
say ref $enc? $enc->name : $enc, "\n";
```

or you can perform a best-guess decoding without checking what the module has chosen

```
  use Encode::Guess qw/ ascii cp1252 iso-8859-1 utf-8 /;

  my $chars = decode("Guess", $data);
```

Remember that the ***fewer*** the possible encodings that you offer, the more likely the guess is to be accurate. You should read the module documentation carefully

#### Update

Here's the OP's one-liner demonstration that `Encode::Guess` *"doesn't do the trick"* written as a proper program

Note that, as the documentation says, `guess_encoding` may sometimes return a string like `utf-8 or iso-8859-1` in which case there is ambiguity that the programmer must handle. *That isn't the case in the OP's example: the data is identified as being UTF-8-encoded, and both `guess_encoding` and `decode('guess', ...)` return the correct results

You can use this code to test `Encode::Guess` with any byte string that you choose: just modify the contents of `$raw`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';
use open qw/ :std encoding(UTF-8) /;

use Encode;
use Encode::Guess;
use Data::Dump;

my $raw = qq/H\x{C3}\x{A9}llo, W\x{C3}\x{B8}rld!/;

my $enc = guess_encoding($raw);

if ( my $class = ref $enc ) {
    printf qq{Guessed encoding \$enc is an %s object "%s"\n}, $class, $enc->name
}
else {
    printf qq{Guessed encoding \$enc is a scalar "%s"\n}, $enc;
}

my $chars = decode('guess', $raw);

printf "Decoded characters: %s\n", $chars;
dd $chars;
```

#### output

```
Guessed encoding $enc is an Encode::utf8 object "utf8"
Decoded characters: Héllo, Wørld!
"H\xE9llo, W\xF8rld!"
```